# Django Social login/register using rest framework

Tags: api, django-rest-framework, google-signin, django-login, social-authentication

I am using DRF as rest framework and want to use the social login for user signup and login. For now, I am using angular to signup with Google which is successful and got following response:

```
"id":"105372307735.........",
"name":"XYZ",
"email":"xyz@gmail.com",
"photoUrl":"https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-C..............",
"authToken":"ya29.Glx2.....................",
"provider":"GOOGLE"
```

How could I use same response to register user and login in django rest framework?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I know it's too late but this might help someone who is struggling with social logins hence posting it here. use this module [django-rest-framework-social-oauth2](https://pypi.org/project/django-rest-framework-social-oauth2/), follow the instructions that are there on their official Github, they have examples for Facebook and Google.

Also, add these pipelines to your settings

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
  'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
  'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
  'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
  'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
  'social_core.pipeline.user.get_username',
  'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_by_email',
  'social_core.pipeline.user.create_user',
  'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
  'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
  'social_core.pipeline.user.user_details',
)
```

This will allow users to authenticate themselves with multiple social logins for a single user account.

Run

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

and

```
python manage.py migrate
```

if you've followed the instructions properly from their official GitHub, then you should be able to visit localhost:8000/auth/convert-token from where you can convert your tokens to your app tokens and use it to authenticate users.